# Family of Moebius transforms with $A(1)=1$ reduces to a single map

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I have a two parameter family of moebius transform $A_{q,p}$ with $q,p\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$A_{q,p}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 2q \\ p&q\end{pmatrix}$$

Additionally, I assume that $A_{q,p}(1)=1$ for all $p,q$. Using the product of the two fixed points, which gives $\dfrac{2q}{p}$, I deduced that necessarily $p=q$ by the formula for the two fixed points I found [here on wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). But this would mean that the whole family only depends on one parameter and its action on the upper half plane is equivalent to
$$A_{q,p}=\begin{pmatrix}0& 2 \\ 1 &1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

This seems somehow counterintuitive. Is this reasoning correct or did I fail to see something here?

Comment: How do you get to assume $A_{q,p}(1)=1$? What is the action on $\Bbb C$?

Comment: The assumption on the fixed point comes from an application in statistical mechanics. It simply translates to that property for the Moebius transformation. The action is $A(z)=\dfrac{2q}{pz+q}$ but I see now that already from this $p=q$ follows... anyway I still do not understand why the whole dependency on $q$ disappears in the action.